# Retrieving selected text with offset values

Tags: php, javascript

I want to annotate  a text and store the annotated text in database .what am doing is, storing the offset values and selected text in the database.Is there is a possible way to retrieving selection using offset values.

Comment: an example will be helpful to understand...

Comment: telling us what database you're using would be every so helpful. Given you're using php, most likely that's mysql, so try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking into [substring() *(php.net)*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

An example of usages is shown on the page

```
<?php
$rest = substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"
$rest = substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef"
$rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns "d"
?>
```